# How do I use different markers using the leafgl package in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

When using the package `leafgl` in R,

**is it possible to use different shapes/markers for the points on the map?**

Instead of a circle I want a triangle (for example).

Many thanks and btw I love this r-package, great job.

Here is some code (from https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl):

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafgl)
library(sf)

n = 1e6

df1 = data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 x = rnorm(n, 10, 3),
                 y = rnorm(n, 49, 1.8))

pts = st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

options(viewer = NULL) # view in browser

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  addGlPoints(data = pts, group = "pts") %>%
  setView(lng = 10.5, lat = 49.5, zoom = 6)
```

Comment: Hi, there's a solution for rendering squares instead of circles (but no triangles, yet). See https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl/pull/54#issuecomment-753979996 for an example. You'd need to re-install from github to get this functionality.

Comment: Thats great, thanks a lot!